How to initialize a union containing const data members in C++11
I am having trouble initializing a union which contains const members in C++11.
In C++20 the problem is avoided by using designated initializers. Example :
union my_union
{
    const void* ptr;
    const double dbl;
};

my_union foo = { .dbl = 42.1 };

However, in C++11 this feature is not available, and it seems the union is always initialized by its first member.
Since the members are const, it also seems that the only way to set a member is via initialization.
I considered using a placement new expression to overwrite the union but I am confused by the lifetime issues related to unions, specifically if placement new "activates" the intended member (https://godbolt.org/z/z4nMTGGeq).
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

union my_union
{
    const void* ptr;
    const double dbl;
};

int main()
{
    my_union foo{};
    new(&foo) double {42.1};
    std::cout << foo.dbl;
}

Is this solution well defined? Or is their better solutions?
The language version and const-ness of the union members are imposed and outside of my control.

Edit : The union is defined by a 3rd party header that can't be changed.

what do you need this union for?

@alagner This union is provided to us as part of an SDK. The SDK API relies on a large structure to describe the user data model. The structure contains several union members whose type resembles the one shown in the question.

Do you have access to C compiler in your project, or does it have it be pure C++? Is a factory function (or rather, multiple ones on C end) that produces (returns) the union acceptable? Then it becomes quite easy but the amount of boilerplate might be significant.

@alagner The project already contains some C source files, so a means of compiling C is always required to be available. The currently investigated solution is to do as you suggest : move the union initialization to a C translation unit. Thank you for the follow up.

You can give the union constructors for the different members:
#include <iostream>

union my_union
{
    my_union(void* ptr_) : ptr(ptr_) {}
    my_union(double dbl_) : dbl(dbl_) {}
    const void* ptr;
    const double dbl;
};

int main()
{
    my_union foo{42.1};
    std::cout << foo.dbl;
}

Outputs:
42.1

Which can be seen in this live example.

Thanks for the answer. I have a constraint that I can't change the header this union is defined in. However, it seems like this change would be ABI compatible. So maybe it can be squeezed in. I'll update the question with the constraint.

Do you have any thoughts on placement new over a union?

@FrançoisAndrieux AFAIK in C++11 the behavior is UB.  I think C++20 makes it implementation defined.

Due to a mix of C and C++ in the same project, this modification turns out to be problematic.

Do you really need to be that strict with C++ standards? GCC (and probably other mainstream compilers) should support designated initializers by means of language extension since forever

@alagner Thanks for the suggestion. The project is compiled with -Wpendantic -Werror on gcc and icx. Removing the flag does allow the use of designated initializers, unfortunately I'm certain this solution would never pass review.

While this answer doesn't apply to my particular set of circumstances, it does generally answer the question asked, so I will accept it..

@FrançoisAndrieux Sorry, IDK how to make this work in C++11 if you can't control the union.  Even using the placement new approach I believe needs std::launder which is a C++17 feature.

@NathanOliver Thanks for your time. I agree with your assessment. It looks like this issue will require revisiting the requirement.

@FrançoisAndrieux FWIW, if you are happy to limit the code to only GCC and Clang then both of those offer designated initializers as an extension.

@NathanOliver isn’t pointer returned by placement new already laundered? If OP is not going to use the original object, but only the placed one maybe he can get away with it?

@alagner With const members it gets a little more complicated.  I'm not 100% sure if its needed but I think it is.

@FrançoisAndrieux no one says to remove global compilation flags, but consider pragmas, e.g. #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wc++20-extensions"
